# Difference in output of GNU and BSD zgrep

Tags: grep, freebsd, gnu

I am using zgrep to search a pattern and print N lines after the matched line from multiple .gz files.

In BSD zgrep I see a separator `--` after each file:

```
zgrep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
$ zgrep  "match string" -A 1 FileName1.log.gz FileName2.log.gz
FileName1.log.gz:match string
FileName1.log.gz-
--
FileName2.log.gz:match string
FileName2.log.gz-
```

But in GNU I do not see the same:

```
zgrep (gzip) 1.6
Copyright (C) 2010-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jean-loup Gailly.

# zgrep  "match string" -A 1 FileName1.log.gz FileName2.log.gz
FileName1.log.gz:match string
FileName1.log.gz:
FileName2.log.gz:match string
FileName2.log.gz:
```

I tried --group-separator but it seems to delimit for matches in single file.

How can I obtain a similar result in GNU zgrep?

Answer (score 1):

You can not get a similar output with GNU `zgrep` (or OpenBSD `zgrep` for that matter, it seems to be particular to `zgrep` on FreeBSD and macOS).  Not unless you do your own post-processing of the results, which is easy:

```
$ zgrep hello file*.gz | awk -F : 'NR > 1 && $1 != name { print "--" } { name = $1; print }'
file1.gz:hello world
--
file2.gz:hello world
--
file3.gz:hello world
--
file4.gz:hello world
--
file5.gz:hello world
```

This passes the output of `zgrep` through a short `awk` program that will insert the separator whenever the filename bit of the line (the bit before the first `:`) changes.